# Collect checkbox values as an array React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a checkbox component, I want my user to be able to check multiple items, and then the items to be saved in the state as an array.

If I select a checkbox my handleChange function seems to set my array to undefined, I'm not sure if it's the way I am sending the data or If I've setup my checkbox wrong, I'm quite new to React.

My main component is

```
export default class MainForm extends Component {
    state = {
        eventFormats: []
    }

    handleChange = input => event => {
        this.setState({[input]: event.target.value})
        console.log(this.state)
    }

    render() {
        const eventFormat = {eventFormats: this.state.eventFormats}
                return <EventFormat
                    nextStep={this.nextStep}
                    handleChange={this.handleChange}
                    values={eventFormat}
        }
    }
}
```

My event form component

```
export default class EventFormat extends Component {
    state = {
        eventFormats: [
            {id: 1, value: 1, label: "Virtual", isChecked: false},
            {id: 2, value: 2, label: "Hybrid", isChecked: false},
            {id: 3, value: 3, label: "Live", isChecked: false},
        ]
    }

    saveAndContinue = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Form>
                <h1 className="ui centered">Form</h1>
                <Form.Field>
                    {
                        this.state.eventFormats.map((format) => {
                            return (<CheckBox handleChange={this.props.handleChange} {...format} />)
                        })
                    }
                </Form.Field>
                <Button onClick={this.saveAndContinue}>Next</Button>
            </Form>
        )
    }
}
```

And finally my checkbox component

```
const CheckBox = (props) => {
    return (<Checkbox label={props.label} onChange={props.handleChange('eventFormats')}/>)
}

export default CheckBox
```

Comment: Yeah, my answer is better as a comment. So you always need to remember, that when you want to console.log the state after setting it you should do it as a callback on setState - this.setState({}, () => {console.log(this.state) }) that is because setState is async. The way you console.log the state in handleChange will not work in a lot of cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your `handleChange` function, which sets state to a dictionary while you said you want the checkbox's value to be added to the `eventFormats` array in the state.

```
export default class MainForm extends Component {
    state = {
        eventFormats: []
    }

    handleChange = input => event => {
        if (event.target.checked) {
            this.setState({eventFormats: this.state.eventFormats.concat([event.target.value])});
        } else {
            const index = this.state.indexOf(event.target.value);
            if (index === -1) {
                console.error("checkbox was unchecked but had not been registered as checked before");
            } else {
                this.setState({eventFormats: this.state.eventFormats.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
        console.log(this.state)
    }

    render() {
        const eventFormat = {eventFormats: this.state.eventFormats}
                return <EventFormat
                    nextStep={this.nextStep}
                    handleChange={this.handleChange}
                    values={eventFormat}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to get into the "checkbox was unchecked" part and then the array is always empty

Comment: Should be fixed now @pocockn I used `.push` which mutates the array but should have used `.concat` which returns the combined array.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to fix:

```
this.setState({[input]: event.target.value})
```

this will always overwrite the array(`eventFormats`) with `event.target.value`.

```
<CheckBox handleChange={this.props.handleChange} {...format} />
```

in the above line, you're passing all the properties in each `format` object

```
const CheckBox = (props) => {
    return (<Checkbox label={props.label} onChange={props.handleChange('eventFormats')}/>)
}
```

but here you're only using `label` and `handleChange`.

---

Here's a [React StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-razsu3?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/App.js) that implements what you're looking for. I used `<input type="checkbox" />`, you can replace this with the `Checkbox` component you want. See the console logs to know how the state looks after toggling any of the checkboxes.

Also, added some comments to help you understand the changes.

```
const Checkbox = ({ id, checked, label, handleChange }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id={id}
        value={checked}
        // passing the id from here to figure out the checkbox to update
        onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}
      />
      <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
    </>
  );
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checkboxes: [
      { id: 1, checked: false, label: "a" },
      { id: 2, checked: false, label: "b" },
      { id: 3, checked: false, label: "c" }
    ]
  };

  handleChange = inputsType => (event, inputId) => {
    const checked = event.target.checked;
    // Functional update is recommended as the new state depends on the old state
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        [inputsType]: prevState[inputsType].map(iT => {
          // if the ids match update the 'checked' prop
          return inputId === iT.id ? { ...iT, checked } : iT;
        })
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.checkboxes);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.checkboxes.map(cb => (
          <Checkbox
            key={cb.id}
            handleChange={this.handleChange("checkboxes")}
            {...cb}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```